# Smartgwt & gwt Show Image From External Folder

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

It is possible to show an image by directly typing

```
Img image = new Image();
image.setSrc("photo.jpg");
```

if photo.jpg is under "images" folder under Web-Content.

I have task to show an image which is in a folder on desktop, is that possible in any way? I did lots of research but not come to a solution. Thanks.

Smartgwt 2.4
Ubuntu 10.10
Gwt 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your structure is something like:

```
myproject
 |-->src
 |||||-->com.myproject
 |||||||||-->client, server, shared
 |-->war
 |||||-->images
```

...you would use images from the `war/images` folder in files within the `client` package by referencing them as `images/image.png`. So your code ought to look like:

```
image.setSrc("images/photo.jpg");
```

The path of the image is relative to the `war` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is images must be beneath {webroot} however it is defined.
In IntelliJ, The path of the image is relative to the default **web** directory , so not necessarily **war**.
If I had the reputation I'd post an image that would explain, but in lieu of that....

```
    GWTapp
      -+.idea
      -+src
         --+client
         --+server
         --+GWTapp.gwt.xml
      -+web
         --+images
           ---+black.gif
         --+WEB-INF
           ---+web.xml
         --+GWTapp.css
         --+GWTapp.html
         --+index.jsp
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you elaborate more on this for the benefit of the OP?  At the very least, you should include a snippet of code that the OP would use to fix their problem.  Also, they never mentioned using IntelliJ.

Comment: It's not about the code, it's all about putting the images directory in the right place. IntelliJ doesn't necessarily use war as shown.  I mentioned IntelliJ to save others the grief of resolving the same problem when war is not present.